# Django request.user becomes anonymous after redirect. Using custom user model and authentication

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am using django 2.1.7  and python 3.6.5 version, extending the django user model with 'AbstractUser' and overwritting django authenticate method. Everything seems to work fine until login, but when the page redirects to home request.user becomes null.

I have tried to render instead of redirecting, this seems to works but then when i open the same page in different tab or refresh the page i got 403 forbidden error (CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.)
Tried the below settings, but still does'nt seem to work
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

settings.py

```py
LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'hygie_portal.CustomUser'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hygie_portal',
    'django_assets',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
                            'hygie_portal.mybackend.MyBackEnd',
)
```

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    def set_is_admin(self, is_admin):
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def set_role(self, role):
        self.last_update = datetime.now()
        self.role = role
```

forms.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.forms import TextInput,EmailInput,PasswordInput

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    """Login form."""

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField( widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

urls.py

```py
app_name = "hygie_portal"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.login_request, name='login'),
    path(r'login/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/login/')),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

view.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
CustomUser = get_user_model()

@csrf_protect
def login_request(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'users/home_public.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user_info = MyBackEnd.authenticate(encode(username), encode(password), request=request)

        if not user_info:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid username or password. Please try again.')
            return redirect('hygie_portal:login')
        is_admin = True if 'manager' in user_info['role'] else False
        try:
            user_profile = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            user_profile = ''

        if not user_profile:
            if 'name' in user_info:
                try:
                    fname = user_info['name'].split()[0]
                except IndexError:
                    fname = ''
                try:
                    sname = user_info['name'].split()[1]
                except IndexError:
                    sname = ''

            else:
                fname, sname = '', ''  
            user_profile = CustomUser(username=username, email=user_info['email'], first_name=fname, last_name=sname, role=user_info['role'])
            user_profile.save()

        try:
            user_profile.set_is_admin(is_admin)
            user_profile.set_role(user_info['role'])
            user_profile.save()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Exception updating user****' % e)
        login(request, user_profile, backend='hygie_portal.mybackend.MyBackEnd')
    #After login request.user.is_authenticated returns true
    #return redirect('hygie_portal:home') #when redirected to home request.user.is_authenticated returns False
    return render(request, 'users/home_public.html') #works fine, but throws 403 error when page is refreshed or url accessed in different tab

    form = LoginForm()   
    if form.errors:
        messages.error(form.errors, 'danger')
        flash(form.errors, 'danger')

    # default to login page if not authenticated or no form submit.
    return render(request, 'public/login.html',{'form': form})

def home(request):  
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'users/home_public.html')
    else:
        return redirect('hygie_portal:login')
```

mybackend.py

```py
class MyBackEnd(object):
    def authenticate(username, password, request=None):
        bind_attr = settings.AD_BIND_ATTR
        user_dn = settings.AD_DN
        login_attr = '(%s=%s)' % (settings.AD_LOGIN_ATTR, username)

        data = get_bind_user(username) #returns the user info with role permissions

        if len(data) == 0:
            return None
        if 'mail' not in data:
            logger.warning('No email found in AD, adding dummy email')
        info['name'] = data['cn'][0] if 'cn' in data else None
        info['email'] = data['mail'][0] if 'mail' in data else 'nomail@xx.com' 
        try:
            info['phone'] = data['telephoneNumber'][0]
        except KeyError:
            info['phone'] = 'Not Available'

        try:
            info['role'] = data['role']
        except KeyError:
            info['role'] = False

        conn = ldap.initialize(settings.AD_URL)
        conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)
        conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, settings.LDAP_PROTOCOL_VERSION)

        try:
            conn.bind_s(data[bind_attr][0].decode(), password)
            conn.search(user_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, login_attr, None)
            conn.result()
            return info
        except (ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS, ldap.OPERATIONS_ERROR):
            logger.info('Invalid credentials for :%s' % username)
            return None

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I have seen in the django docs the login() will save the user's ID for the entire session. I want the session to be accessed across different tabs once the user is logged in.

I have tried to check the session details using request.session, but i dont know how to use it in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your `get_user` method. It should accept the user ID, not the username, and use that to look up the model instance.

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

**Django uses `AuthenticationMiddleware` to attach the user object to the `httpRequest` object.**

When you `login()` the user, it will save the `users.id` along with the `backend` reference to the session:

```
login(request, user, backend='your.auth.backend')
```

This allows the `AuthenticationMiddleware` to later use the same backend to fetch the `user` object and attach it to the `httpRequest`.
It does this by calling the `get_user()` method, passing the `user_id` as the argument.

Its important that you do not override the `get_user()` to accept anything other than the primary key or user id

More info can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend][2]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend%5D%5B2%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `'django.contrib.sessions'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`? 
You should consider using [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions).

By default, Django saves session information in database (django_session table or collection), but you can configure the engine to store information using other ways like: in file or in cache. When session is enabled, every request (first argument of any view in Django) has a session (dict) attribute.
You can use session dict in order to manually store `User` information like

```
request.session['username'] = username

request.session['email'] = email
```

Comment: i have 'django.contrib.sessions' already in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, edited the code. i am new to django, can you explain in detail how to add the user to the session dict and make sure that request.user.is_authenticated is true if the user is already logged in.  Is this a good way of implementing ??