# Next redirected view indicates anonymous user even though login was successful

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

So I have this code. However, although I am able to login correctly with `sessionid` set, the redirected view still indicates `request.user.is_authenticated` is False. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
class TeacherLoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, TemplateView):
    form_class = TeacherLoginForm
    template_name = 'accounts/teacher-login.html'
    success_message = 'Logged in Successfully!'
    error_message = 'Staff ID or Password incorrect!'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        message = ''
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form, 'message': message})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = TeacherBackend.authenticate(self, username=form.cleaned_data['staff_id'],
                                               password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                               )
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user, backend='accounts.backends.backends.TeacherBackend')
                return redirect('accounts:home')
            else:
                messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form})
```

Comment: Why are you using `request.GET` in a post method?

Comment: I am using  request.GET.get('next') it to get the "next" parameter in the url

Answer (score 0):

Realised the issue was in the custom auth backend I had coded. I needed to add the `get_user` method. thanks to this answer too [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64500678/3278083),  [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127261/3278083)

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```